# How do I add custom data-bindings to knockoutjs' template binding

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am currently using the ExternalTemplate extension to have my templates loaded via ajax at runtime. However I am looking to extend this functionality slightly so I can supply more than one template directory.

I know it seems a bit bizarre, but I have a couple of places where templates could come from, and it is not possible to have them all coming out of one big template folder unfortunately.

I was hoping to do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var templateEngineSettings = {
    templatesLocations: { 
        "default":"/view-templates-1"
        "other1":"/view-templates-2"
        "other2":"/somewhere-else/view-templates"
    },
    templateSuffix: ".template.html" 
};

ko.externaljQueryTemplateEngine.setOptions(templateEngineSettings);
</script>

<div data-bind="template: {name: 'some-template', location:'default'}"></div>
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'some-other-template', location:'other1'}"></div>
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'some-new-template', location:'other3'}"></div>
```

However I cannot find any solid documentation on how to do this, so any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The external template engine pulls its url base from:

`ko.ExternalTemplateEngine.templateUrl`

One choice would be to create a wrapper to the template binding that would swap this value from your template locations.  Something like:

```
//custom binding
ko.bindingHandlers.templatex = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var options = valueAccessor(),
            location = options.location,
            current = koExternalTemplateEngine.templateUrl;

        //set to our new location
        ko.ExternalTemplateEngine.templateUrl = ko.bindingHandlers.templatex.templateLocations[location];

        //call the real template binding
        ko.bindingHandlers.update.tempate(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);

        //reset the location back to the default
        ko.ExternalTemplateEngine.templateUrl = current;
    },
    templateLocations: {}
};

//set in your app code
ko.bindingHandlers.templatex.templateLocations = {
    "default":"/view-templates-1",
    "other1":"/view-templates-2",
    "other2":"/somewhere-else/view-templates"
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, will take a more in depth when I get home later. I was going to make a possible branch of the external template code, to support multiple templates if I could, but this may be a better approach, if all the changes are just in one place rather than 2 (knockoujs extension, custom external template build)